# jgroups marshling exception

Tags: java, infinispan, jgroups

using jgroups 3.6
with infinspan 8.2

spring java.

while updating replicated cache
getting this jgroup related exception

org.jboss.marshalling.TraceInformation

307978 [WARN] CommandAwareRpcDispatcher: ISPN000220: Problems un-marshalling remote command from byte buffer
c4i2  | java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.util.Date field JsonObject.endtime to java.lang.String

1 solution failed - setting application properties
hibernate.session_factory_name=MySessionFactory
hibernate.session_factory_name_is_jndi=false

thanks.